# Spring Cloud Gateway match multiple path elements

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

Spring Cloud Greenwich puts `spring-cloud-netflix-zuul` in maintenance mode, so I am trying to migrate from Zuul to Spring Cloud Gateway.

With Zuul I have a route like

```
zuul:
  routes:
    masterplan_match:
      path: /**/masterplans/**
      serviceId: api-masterplan
```

What I am doing there is basically ignoring everything that comes before or after `masterplan` in the received path and redirect to `api-masterplan`. For example, both `/some/path/to/masterplans` and `/masterplans` goes to the same api (the reason being `masterplans` are a subresource of a bigger entity, which is responsible for creating new `masterplans`, but then `masterplans` can be treated as full blown resources for purposes like `GET`ting details, updating, deleting).

Can I map this configuration to Spring Cloud Gateway? Looking at [predicates](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#gateway-request-predicates-factories), the feasible one seems to be [path predicate](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_path_route_predicate_factory), but then it looks like all matchers work on individual path elements (except the `WildcardTheRestPathElement`, which however can be used only as last element - I think), ie: I would need to write something like

```
spring
    cloud:
      gateway:
        routes:
        - id: masterplan_match
          uri: lb://api-masterplan # Coming from discovery client
          predicates:
          - Path=/some/path/to/masterplans/**, /masterplans/**
```

Am I missing something and can the two paths be condensed in one?

Comment: Does this solved ur problem ?  `- Path=/some/path/to/masterplans/**, /masterplans/**`

Comment: @Som sorry for the late reply, afair it did not help. in the meantime I solved the problem somehow but also changed company and honestly don't remember how. plus there has probably been a lot of development on Spring Cloud Gateway, but unfortunately did not have any chance to use that project again

Comment: No Problem buddy. I resolved it anyway. Thanks for your reply. Cheers !

Comment: Confirm this works now...couldn't find it anywhere in the docs tho....

Answer (score 13):

Spring Cloud Gateway support multiple patterns since version `2.1.0`

```
spring
    cloud:
      gateway:
        routes:
        - id: masterplan_match
          uri: lb://api-masterplan # Coming from discovery client
          predicates:
          - Path=/some/path/to/masterplans/**, /masterplans/**
```

See Also:

[Add support for multiple paths in path predicate #256](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/pull/256)

[Multiple patterns in Host Route Predicate #589](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/589)